# GeoServer PostGIS store does not seem to follow schema search_path

Tags: postgis, geoserver

GeoServer 12.16.2, PostgreSQL 14.5, PostGIS 3.2.1

I have a view of vector data named `geomorphic_data_verbose` in the `sys` database schema.  The database `search_path` is `"$user",sys`.  I can successfully run the query `SELECT * FROM geomorphic_data_verbose;` (no schema qualifier) in the `psql` interpreter.

In GeoServer, I have set up a PostGIS store pointed at this database.  In the store configuration, I have left the `schema` empty, since it is not required.  I have also set up a layer from that store to read from the `geomorphic_data_verbose` view.  However, when I try to query that layer, GeoServer throws this error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "public.geomorphic_data_verbose" does not exist
```

If I edit the store and explicitly set schema to `sys`, then the query works fine.

So, does GeoServer not follow the `search_path` in PostGIS?  If left blank, it seems to default to the `public` schema, which is not where the view lives.

Comment: The `search_path` lookup kicks in only if a relation identifier is unqualified - and since GeoServer seems to default to `public`, you are required to add your schema in.

Comment: GeoServer stores are linked explicitly to a schema, with a default of public. So this is as expected

Comment: Thanks @IanTurton.  Is this Geoserver behavior documented anywhere?  I have searched rather extensively, but must have overlooked it if it exists.

Comment: Rtfs  if you think the docs need updating there is any edit button on every page.